# JComboBox no se carga con datos

Tags: java

Cordial saludo. Estoy intentando desarrollar una aplicación de escritorio en Java y al cargar los datos de un JComboBox éstos no aparecen. Estoy utilizando un modelo en capas. Este es el código del DAO:

```
    public static ArrayList<AbastosOpLog> LisAbasDisp(){
      ArrayList <AbastosOpLog> abastosop = new ArrayList<>();
      Connection connection = null;
      Conexion conex = new Conexion();
      PreparedStatement statement = null;
      ResultSet result = null;

      AbastosOpLog abasop = new AbastosOpLog(); 

      connection = conex.getConnection();

      String consulta = "select abascod , abasdesc from abop001";

      try{
         if(connection != null){
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(consulta);
            result = statement.executeQuery();

               while(result.next() == true)
               {
                  abasop.setAbas_cod(result.getString("abas_cod"));
                  abasop.setAbas_desc(result.getString("abas_desc"));
                  abastosop.add(abasop);
               }
         }
      }catch (SQLException e) {
         System.out.println("Error en la consulta de Abastos: "+e.getMessage());
      }finally{
       try {
        connection.close();
        conex.desconectar();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }

     return abastosop;
   }
```

Y el método que lo carga en la vista:

```
private void LlenarOpAbastos() {
         cblisopt.removeAllItems();
          AbastosOpDao miAbastosOpDao = new AbastosOpDao();
         ArrayList <AbastosOpLog> abastoop = AbastosOpDao.LisAbasDisp();

         for (int i = 0; i < abastoop.size(); i++) {
          cblisopt.addItem(abastoop.get(i).getAbas_cod() + "-" + abastoop.get(i).getAbas_desc());
         }
         //lblMsj.setText(cblisopt.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }
```

¿En dónde puede estar el error?, el código lo diseñé a partir de éste que encontré. http://codejavu.blogspot.com/2017/03/como-llenar-un-jcombobox-con-datos-de.html gracias por su ayuda.

/*****************************************************************************/

Ya me carga el `JComboBox`. Sí había un error en la consulta `SQL`.
Pero ahora me carga el último `Item` de la lista y me trae 15 veces el último valor de la lista.

El `ResultSet` lee 15 veces la última fila.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es el `try` que setea los valores:

```
try{
     if(connection != null){
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(consulta);
        result = statement.executeQuery();

           while(result.next() == true)
           {
              abasop.setAbas_cod(result.getString("abas_cod"));
              abasop.setAbas_desc(result.getString("abas_desc"));
              abastosop.add(abasop);
           }
     }
  }
```

Y el código que llena el `JComboBox`

```
 private void LlenarOpAbastos() {
     cblisopt.removeAllItems();
      AbastosOpDao miAbastosOpDao = new AbastosOpDao();
     ArrayList <AbastosOpLog> abastoop = AbastosOpDao.LisAbasDisp();

     for (int i = 0; i < abastoop.size(); i++) {
      cblisopt.addItem(abastoop.get(i).getAbas_cod() + "-" + abastoop.get(i).getAbas_desc());
     }
     //lblMsj.setText(cblisopt.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te marca algún error o solo no carga los datos.

Comment: No carga los datos.

Comment: ¿Dónde se hace la llamada al método LlenarOpAbastos() ?

Comment: En el constructor de la clase que extiende el JFrame: public Abastos() {LlenarOpAbastos();}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondo mi pregunta con la respuesta que me dieron en Stackoverflow en inglés:

> Estás añadiendo la misma instancia una y otra vez. Crea una nueva
>   instancia en cada iteración (removiendo la declaración previa
>   también):

```
       while (rs.next())
       {
          AbastosOpLog abasop = new AbastosOpLog(); 
          abasop.setAbas_cod(rs.getString("abascod"));
          abasop.setAbas_desc(rs.getString("abasdesc"));
          abastosop.add(abasop);
       }
```

Comment: traduce el contenido de esta respuesta por favor, pues estas en la versión en español de SO

Answer (score 0):

El error al parecer esta en la consulta de la Query...

```
private void cargarDivisiones() {
    conectar cc = new conectar();
    Connection cn = cc.conexion();


        String nombrecliente = (String) cmbCliente.getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println(nombrecliente);

        String query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombrecliente LIKE nombrecliente";
        try {
            PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(query);
            result = pst.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                cmbDivision.addItem(result.getString("divisiones"));  //aca es donde cargas la informacion de la query en el combobox 
            }

            cn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Loq_Insertar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


}
```

Comment: Hola, no creo que necesite una cláusula WHERE en la consulta, y pues necesito concatenar las columnas abas_cod y abas_desc para agregarlas como un sólo Item en el JComboBox